# Delay Sum Beamforming in Python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am trying to implement a simple delay-sum beamformer using a 4 Microphone Array. I am using MATLAB at the moment, which has an inbuilt Signal Processing toolkit that is quite helpful. I was wondering if there are such tools in Python. For starters, i want to know how to get an audio signal from a microphone in real time and have a continuous plot as a preliminary output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pyAudio you can get the audio signal from mic in real time.

http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

to plot it, you can use matplotlib or Chaco:

Chaco has an example that use pyAudio and plot the spectrum of the audio signal:

https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/master/examples/demo/advanced/spectrum.py